# pkgin on Ubuntu with VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I'm attempting to execute a binary file via the command line in Ubuntu which is being supported by VMWare. When attempting to perform this task I get:

```
Error opening terminal: xterm
```

It looks like this is something encountered by others as well, as it provides a [remedy here](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/MinixFaq) (5.2)

The proposed fix is to install pkgin on my VMWare box. So, I follow the instructions [found here](http://pkgin.net/) to install. Everything looks find until I try to "make". I get:

```
No targets specified and no makefile found
```

Any ideas or help? I could be missing something obvious, as I don't use Linux very frequently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unwise to follow a document about MINIX when trying to debug problems on Ubuntu. The advice will probably not carry over well. `pkgin` is used for MINIX (and apparently some other systems) package installation. `apt-get` is used for Ubuntu package installation.

To install `xterm` on Ubuntu, run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

Comment: The odd thing is that xterm is already installed. Even when using the xterm terminal, I still get the same error "Error opening terminal: xterm" I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: How about running `xterm` by hand in a terminal? I haven't yet figured out how to get that error message...

Comment: Running xterm pops open the xterm window (as one would expect). However, just as I mentioned before when attempting to run (even within the xterm command window) it still gives the same error. 

The error may be specific to running Ubuntu through VMWare perhaps?

Comment: Alright, I think I fixed the problem and it was certainly a result of my misunderstanding. I was simply calling the program with incorrect parameters. Why I ended up with this error, I'm not quite sure. Thanks again for your help!